# I have .Kismet files in my root directory. Where could they come from and are they dangerous?

Tags: malware, linux, sniffing, kismet

I use Parrot OS security.
When i was listing the contents in my root dir i noticed some weird file names that end with **.Kismet**.
I know that kismet is a network intrusion detection software which is also used for wifi sniffing etc... But i never installed or used it.
Here are the suspicious files:

Kismet-20200404-18-30-16-1.kismet
Kismet-20200408-19-52-16-1.kismet
Kismet-20200414-14-48-01-1.kismet
Kismet-20200405-17-25-29-1.kismet
Kismet-20200408-20-00-22-1.kismet
Kismet-20200415-19-36-28-1.kismet
Kismet-20200410-16-59-20-1.kismet
Kismet-20200417-13-32-41-1.kismet-journal

As you can see they re named with date and time. When i try to open them, most of it is encrypted and unreadable. Here is some of the readable stuff:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (ts_sec INT, lat REAL, lon REAL, msgtype TEXT, message TEXT )��wtablealertsalerts CREATE TABLE alerts (ts_sec INT, ts_usec INT,
```

I never installed kismet on my machine and I think it is not in the parrot default install included. So does anyone know where these files could come from and whether or not they 're dangerous?

Comment: Have you looked up if Kismet is installed by default on Parrot? Have you looked in `/bin`? From the Parrot repo, it appears to be included in the standard build

Comment: It is the standart built yeah! But still, that doesnt explain why some random files appear in my root dir. And since they're named by date and time marks it seems like they re some sort of scans or logs...

Answer (score 1):

ParrotOS being a security distro [includes this IDS](https://github.com/ParrotSec/parrot-tools/blob/master/debian/control) as part of the package `parrot-tools`. Learn more about how the logging can be configured [here](https://www.kismetwireless.net/docs/readme/logging/).

Those log files are a type of sqlite file. They are not encrypted but binary files. You can access their content using sqlite, an sqlite browser, or Kismet itself by using `kismetdb_statistics`.

Please refer to ParrotOS documentation and Kismet documentation for more information about this.